# How do I assign a radio button a value and retrieve that value later in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, radio-button, adt

I'm new at programming for Android and I've been looking for days on an answer for my question with no luck. I'm trying to assign my radio button a value of 110 and I want to receive it later. Can anyone show me how I can achieve this in the xml and java file?

Here's what I have for my radio button. Standard.

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/N110" />
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `tag` property of `View`s to store and retrieve additional data.

To set the `tag` in XML:

```
android:tag="@string/some_value"
```

To retrieve the `tag` in Java:

```
myView.getTag().toString()
```

To set the `tag` in Java:

```
myView.setTag("someValue");
```

Or if the value will be the same as just the title of the radio button, you could just get the title from it:

```
myView.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Would the tag be a String or an Item in the strings.xml file?

Comment: I believe it can be either. Not in front of my IDE.

Comment: in html we can use Valuew property,,so tag property work same as like it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tag property of radio buttons as follows:

To set the value in your code:

```
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
rb.setTag("YOUR TAG VALUE");
```

And to retrieve it:

```
String retrievedValue = rb.getTag().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the component using this code in OnCreateView:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourXMLLayoutName, group, false);

RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
Log.d("text value of radioButton", String.valueOf(radio.getText()));
```